# Qmail Log: lots of UNAUTHENTICATED SENDER

Tags: qmail

On qmail logs there are lots of the following lines:

```
2012-12-14 18:04:49.314299500 simscan:[9999]:CLEAN (4.00/50.00):2.2875s:Delivery Status Notification (Failure):aa.aa.aa.aa::info@xxxx.it
2012-12-14 18:04:49.657999500 CHKUSER accepted rcpt: from <::> remote <utility-xxxx.it:unknown:aa.aa.aa.aa> rcpt <info@xxx.it> : found existing recipient
2012-12-14 18:04:49.658005500 policy_check: local  -> local info@xxxx.it (UNAUTHENTICATED SENDER)
2012-12-14 18:04:49.658016500 policy_check: policy allows transmission
2012-12-14 18:04:49.658019500 spamdyke[9945]: ALLOWED from: (unknown) to: info@xxxx.it origin_ip: 82.85.185.32 origin_rdns: utility-xxxxx.it auth: (unknown)
```

and

```
12-14 18:03:57 CHKUSER accepted rcpt: from <::> remote <utility-xxxx.it:unknown:aa.aa.aa.aa> rcpt <info@xxxx.it> : found existing recipient
12-14 18:03:57 policy_check: local  -> local info@xxxx.it (UNAUTHENTICATED SENDER)
12-14 18:03:57 spamdyke[9945]: ALLOWED from: (unknown) to: info@xxxx.it origin_ip: aa.aa.aa.aa origin_rdns: utility-xxxx.it auth: (unknown)
12-14 18:03:59 simscan:[9999]:CLEAN (4.00/50.00):2.4153s:Delivery Status Notification (Failure):aa.aa.aa.aa::info@xxxx.it
12-14 18:04:00 CHKUSER accepted rcpt: from <::> remote <utility-xxxx.it:unknown:aa.aa.aa.aa> rcpt <info@xxxx.it> : found existing recipient
12-14 18:04:00 policy_check: local  -> local info@xxxx.it (UNAUTHENTICATED SENDER)
12-14 18:04:00 spamdyke[9945]: ALLOWED from: (unknown) to: info@xxxx.it origin_ip: aa.aa.aa.aa origin_rdns: utility-xxxx.it auth: (unknown)
12-14 18:04:02 simscan:[9999]:CLEAN (4.00/50.00):2.5481s:Delivery Status Notification (Failure):aa.aa.aa.aa::info@xxxx.it
12-14 18:04:02 CHKUSER accepted rcpt: from <::> remote <utility-xxxx.it:unknown:aa.aa.aa.aa> rcpt <info@xxxx.it> : found existing recipient
12-14 18:04:02 policy_check: local  -> local info@xxxx.it (UNAUTHENTICATED SENDER)
12-14 18:04:02 spamdyke[9945]: ALLOWED from: (unknown) to: info@xxxx.it origin_ip: aa.aa.aa.aa origin_rdns: utility-xxxx.it auth: (unknown)
```

Does this mean something unwanted?
Thank you... I'm completely new to qmail

Answer (score 0):

possibly these are the bounce message recieved by the user info@xxxx.it

> 12-14 18:03:57 CHKUSER accepted rcpt: from <::> remote  rcpt  : found existing recipient

It is possible that someone has spoofed the mail id of sender and might be performing some  spam activity. And as we all know spammers send mails to random ids and most of which do-not exists. In return the sender id would get a bounce message.

Just verify it.